# File Not found exception - speechclient.dll NuGet Package

Tags: nuget, azure-cognitive-services

I have a project using the `SpeechClient.dll` from NuGet. The program runs fine on the development machine. So I have a Windows Setup Project that creates the installer. I run the installer and all the files show up including the `SpeechClient.dll`, but as soon as the program makes the first call to the `Speechclient.dll`, I get a

> file not found

exception. This is the output from the event viewer.

[image: Picture Here]

Does anyone have any troubleshooting ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems now that I have installed visual studio on the machine that it is working. I wonder what visual studio installs? I was also trying to use Fusion Log Viewer to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. Installing the [Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2017 x64](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572) cleared it up.